# Error when Converting Text Parameter to Numeric Type for Y-Axis in Power BI Bar Chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm encountering an issue in Power BI while attempting to create a parameterized field. When I place the parameterized field on the Y-axis of a bar chart, it's not being recognized. However, when I use individual fields separately, the chart works fine. Upon inspecting the field's type, it appears to be of text type, preventing me from converting the parameter to a numeric type. I receive the following error message: "Cannot convert value 'Cos' from Text type to Number type while processing the Parameter column." How can I resolve this error and successfully convert the parameter to a numeric type for use in my bar chart's Y-axis?